# CSS scroll no body

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, rolamento

Tenho uma estrutura com 2 colunas ([Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)), uma sendo o menu, e a outra o `content,` com valor setado e umas 3 imagens grandes dentro deste `content` que gera um `scroll.`

Entanto, também estou com um `scroll` no `body` da página, resultando em 2 `scroll` o do `body` e o do `content.`

Alguém sabe como retirar o `scroll` do `body` e permanecer com o `scroll` do  `content`?

Comment: Tem como disponibilizar o print dessa situação ou uma parte do código para tentarmos entender o que você precisa?

Comment: Sabrina, edita a pergunta e posta código por favor, fica mais fácil de resolver.

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você pode fazer o uso do [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp), assim:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

O código acima vai esconder o `scroll` horizontal e vertical.

Se você quer esconder somente o `scroll`  vertical, use `overflow-y`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Se você quer esconder somente o `scroll`horizontal, use `overflow-x`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Observe o uso do [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) no `snippet` abaixo:

```css
.content {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  padding: .5em;
  
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 5em;
  /*overflow: hidden;        /* SEM SCROLL */
  overflow-y: scroll;    /* COM SCROLL VERTICAL */
  /*overflow-x: scroll;    /* COM SCROLL HORIZONTAL */
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu
urna et leo aliquet malesuada ut ac dolor. Fusce non arcu vel ligula
fermentum sodales a quis sapien. Sed imperdiet justo sit amet venenatis
egestas. Integer vitae tempor enim. In dapibus nisl sit amet purus congue
tincidunt. Morbi tincidunt ut eros in rutrum. Sed quam erat, faucibus
vel tempor et, elementum at tortor. Praesent ac libero at arcu eleifend
mollis ut eget sapien. Duis placerat suscipit eros, eu tempor tellus
facilisis a. Vivamus vulputate enim felis, a euismod diam elementum
non. Duis efficitur ac elit non placerat. Integer porta viverra nunc,
sed semper ipsum. Nam laoreet libero lacus.

Sed sit amet tincidunt felis. Sed imperdiet, nunc ut porta elementum,
eros mi egestas nibh, facilisis rutrum sapien dolor quis justo. Quisque
nec magna erat. Phasellus vehicula porttitor nulla et dictum. Sed
tincidunt scelerisque finibus. Maecenas consequat massa aliquam pretium
volutpat. Duis elementum magna vel velit elementum, ut scelerisque
odio faucibus.
</div>
```

Pode-se fazer uso também do  [::-webkit-scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar), veja um exemplo no [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwwugsyb/).

Comment: Muito obrigada !